# LINQ dont want display in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008

I want to display all records from table of current autorized user in my ASP.NET-MVC 3 + SQL Server 2008 app. But I have some problems:

this code with LINQ-request working good:

```
public ActionResult Index(todo obj)
        {
           string u = User.Identity.Name; 
           var th = (from tt in _db.todo select tt);
           return View(th);
        }
```

but this code not work:

```
public ActionResult Index(todo obj)
          {
             string u = User.Identity.Name; 
             var th = (from tt in _db.todo where obj.login == u select tt);
             return View(th);
           }
```

and this code is working good

```
if (u == obj.login) { ViewBag.res = "ok"; } else { ViewBag.res = "fail"; }
```

What I do wrong, please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to run your where criteria against the table you're querying, instead of against the argument from the method, i.e.:

`var th = (from tt in _db.todo where tt.login == u select tt);`

Comment: Oh no
it was epic fail!
very grateful to You, thanx :)

Answer (score 0):

instead of `obj.login == u`, try

```
obj.Contains(u)
```